# Let A be the n × n matrix whose i, j entry is i + j for all i, j = 1, 2, . . . , n. What is the rank of A?

Tags: linear-algebra

I tried finding the solution by assuming i and j are both n, but I'm not sure if this is the proper direction to go.

Comment: It looks like you may have a fundamental misunderstanding of what the matrix looks like.  Try writing out the matrix for, say, a $3 \times 3$ example and see if that helps you understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: the first column is $\mathbf v=(2,3,\dots,n)^T$. Furthermore, the $i$th column is given by $\mathbf v+(i-1)\mathbf 1$ where $\mathbf 1\in\mathbb R^n$ is the vector whose entries are all $1$s. What does this tell you about the number of column vectors of the matrix that are linearly independent?

Comment: Not that it changes the argument at all, but the entries in the first column are $2,3,....,n,n+1$.

Comment: @Ned you're right, I will update the answer.